# How to listen to the state of a running process using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, state

I am writing an installer using C# and WPF. The installer starts and hides another installer. So basically it's just to provide a more beautiful User Interface. My problem is that my program doesn't know when the installing and therefor the started process is terminated.
Is there a possibility to listen to the state of the started process that runs in the back?

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the process and you can wait for it to exit in between if there are other states which you wanted to know might be difficult to know

```
var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit();
```

It also has an overload where you can specify the timeout, so you're not potentially waiting forever. You can [read more on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx)

Comment: thank you, I am going to check this soon and then mark it as an answer!